# Treasure adventure game miner boss problem

Tags: treasure-adventure-game

I got stuck on "miner boss" (that giant two-legged miner drill that the pirates pilot and that throws dynamites on me) and i can not find a way to hurt him.

All I found out by trial and error is that when i hit it into cockpit that animation shows as if energy shield was present, but no animation suggesting that it would be hurt by it. when i try to throw bomb on it, it just falls trough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out a way.

after you throw bomb on bot, he awkward rises his leg. I had this for weird animation or glitch, but it is what is supposed to happen and you have to crawl underneath it and then proceed to miner cart and shoot its cannon on bot.